# C++ static member variable of type enum won't compile

Tags: c++, static, enums

I'm trying to write a class with a public enum, and a private static member variable of that enum type. I can initialise the value of the static variable, but if I try to access it in a class member function, my code won't link.  Here's a simple working example that will compile with:

```
g++ -o TestClass.o TestClass.cpp
```

but then fails when I try to compile/link the main source file with:

```
g++ -o test TestClass.o testmain.cpp
```

The error I get is:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "TestClass::_enum", referenced from:
      TestClass::printEnum()     in TestClass.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

I'm using a Mac running OSX 10.7.5, with gcc 4.2.1.

TestClass.h:

```
#ifndef TEST_CLASS_H
#define TEST_CLASS_H

class TestClass
{
public:
  TestClass() {};  
  void printEnum();

  typedef enum {A, B, C} MyEnum;

private:
  static MyEnum _enum;


};

#endif
```

TestClass.cpp:

```
#include "TestClass.h"

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

TestClass::MyEnum _enum = TestClass::A;

void TestClass::printEnum()
{
  cout << "Value of enum: " << _enum << endl;
}
```

testmain.cpp:

```
#include "TestClass.h"

int main()
{
  TestClass tc;

  tc.printEnum();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code below declares a file local variable `_enum` of type `TestClass::MyEnum`.  It is not providing the definition for your static member variable.

```
TestClass::MyEnum _enum = TestClass::A;
```

To do that, you have to specifically define it in the appropriate class scope, like this:

```
TestClass::MyEnum TestClass::_enum = TestClass::A;
```

Answer (score 0):

Static member outside class is not defined properly
proper format:
classname::enumtype staticmember = value;

in your example it is
TestClass::MyEnum _enum = TestClass::A;